# Plot grid graph with latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, grids

I have no idea to plot the following graph. I don't need the bold shade. Can anyone help me. Thank you in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple foreach is enough. The grid without the numbers can also be done with `\draw (0,0) grid (6,4);` and this can be modified as any other path. You can also specify the step, which in this case is not needed because the drawing uses `1cm` and Tikz uses the same value by default.

Since you want custom numbers and you're loading `pgfmath` through Tikz, you can use arrays. The number `404` is there because you gave me only 4 numbers for the second row, so it was... *not found*.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    dot/.style 2 args={fill, circle, inner sep=1pt, label={#1:\scriptsize #2}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\def\numberlist{{3,0,1,0,2,3,0,2,1,404,2,1,0,6,7,1,1,3,4,5,1,3,2,1,0}} 
\def\maxX{4}
\foreach \x [count=\n] in {0,...,\maxX}{
    \foreach \y in {0,...,4}{
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\tmp{\n+(\maxX+1)*\y}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\num{\numberlist[\tmp-1]}
        \draw[line width=.5pt] (\x,0) -- (\x,4);
        \draw[line width=.5pt] (0,\y) -- (\maxX,\y);
        \node[dot={45}{\num}] at (\x,\y) {};
    }
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Alenano Thank you so much for your answer. How can change the label of a node?

Comment: @ThomasEdison It depends. In what way do you want to change them?

Comment: I want to change 1,2,3,4,5 ... to 3,0,1,2,1,.... This sequence does not has any rule.

Comment: @ThomasEdison None whatsoever? What's the full sequence of numbers you need?

Comment: I only need to plot in 5x5 grid with label are 
row 1: 3,0,1,0,2. row 2: 3,0,2,1, row 3: 2,1,0,6,7, row 4: 1,1,3,4,5, row 5: 1,3,2,1,0

Comment: @ThomasEdison See edit.

Comment: @ThomasEdison next time make sure to show the details sooner in your question. :)